# Accurately test upload / download on mobile devices?

Tags: php, http, ftp, download, throughput

I know this has been asked 1000 times, but I would still like to gather further clarification on the issue I face.

I am trying to test the throughput on mobile devices (LTE, 3G, 2G). I am looking for a solution which is very accurate (within reason!).

My original solution was to use an FTP server to perform upload and download tests, however I face the issue that the FTP server I use is simply not quick enough to support LTE. Getting a new FTP server isn't an option at this stage. I must also take into consideration how many HOPS it takes to get to the server.

I am not looking for a ready made solution like SpeedTest.net, I need something raw so that I can program my own scripts. I was thinking of doing something in PHP (HTTP upload and download?)

My idea was to have some sort of script on a PHP Server. However won't this be testing the servers speed, rather than the devices?

I forgot to mention that I will be testing the devices via internet tethering :)

Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If your server has a slower upload speed than the download speed of a phone. get a new internet line or server

Comment: As I said, a new server isn't an option. I have seen LTE reach speeds of 90 mb/s. My FTP server is throttled at 30 mb/s. Clearly not a viable solution.